# Is the LOCC-assisted quantum channel capacity of a degradable quantum channel additive?

Tags: resource-request, channel-capacity

The LOCC-assisted quantum channel capacity refers to the maximum rate of faithful quantum information transmission through the channel when classical communications and local operations are also allowed. The fact that the unassisted quantum capacity of a quantum channel equals the coherent information whenever the channel is degradable is a well known result.

I was wondering if such thing is the same for the LOCC-assisted quantum channel capacity, i.e. if such information theoretic quantity is additive for channels with a degrading CPTP map from the output to the environment.